# Start docker container from Java

Tags: java, docker, cucumber

I am trying to run automation test cases using docker and cucumber, Is there a way to integrate both things together which means we have one process which will build image,  run container and eventually trigger our cucumber.

Comment: Why not use an existing solution for this such as Jenkins?

Comment: @Marit then... don't push to master? What does this have to do with the question? Also in most workflows you... never push to master. But that's off topic for the question.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client) of use?

Comment: @Marit well then you are not talking about test automation anymore though? Just... run your tests then?

Comment: @ben .. can we start and stop docker using jenkins... Also is it possible to verify that yes our docker container is up and ready for tests...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Gradle (import [docker plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin)).
Or just use the docker API for Java that @jrtapsell linked.